# Cannot use List Comprehension from data read in .csv file (using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing the following

```
data = pd.read_csv("MyFileCSV.csv")
entry1 = list(data["first column"])

# I want to create a subset of elements in entry1: the datatype in the csv-file is surely float
# attempt 1: Time = entry1[x for x in entry1 if 10<x<20] invalid syntax
# attempt 2: Time = [entry1[x for x in entry1 if 10<x<20]] invalid syntax again
```

How do I solve this? Thanks